# Cygwin breaks net use Z: /delete in scripts?

Tags: bash, cygwin

Cygwin somehow breaks unmounting of network shares, but ONLY if the
`net use /delete` happens in a bash shell script.

Example:
Mount SMB network share on Z:
Do not touch Z:!

Then do a net use /delete in a bash script:

`net use Z: /delete`

Result:

> Systemfehler 1794 aufgetreten.
> Der Redirector wird verwendet und kann nicht aus dem Speicher entfernt werden.

If I execute the `net use Z: /delete` in an interactive bash shell it works.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: The error in English: "The redirector is in use and cannot be unloaded." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1700-3999-)

Comment: Could it be that some process in the bash script is using z:/ (i.e. still has open handles to an entry of the share)? If you suspect that this is specific to bash (I doubt somehow), try the same in a different shell script (for instance in zsh), to see whether you get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

```
I think it's the problem that a shell keeps a fd open to the shell
script's file.

Example:
---- snip ----
$ cat shellfd.ksh
#!/bin/ksh93
# shell script printing the fd which the shell
# process has open right now
ls -l /proc/$$/fd/
true # needed here so ksh93 doesn't make a tail optimisation
exit 0
$ bash shellfd.ksh
total 0
lrwx------ 1 test001 users 64 Aug 13 00:26 0 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 test001 users 64 Aug 13 00:26 1 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 test001 users 64 Aug 13 00:26 2 -> /dev/pts/7
lr-x------ 1 test001 users 64 Aug 13 00:26 255 -> /cygdrive/h/tmp/shellfd.ksh
$ ksh93 shellfd.ksh
total 0
lrwx------ 1 test001 users 64 Aug 13 00:26 0 -> /dev/pts/7
lrwx------ 1 test001 users 64 Aug 13 00:26 1 -> /dev/pts/7
lr-x------ 1 test001 users 64 Aug 13 00:26 10 -> /cygdrive/h/tmp/shellfd.ksh
lrwx------ 1 test001 users 64 Aug 13 00:26 2 -> /dev/pts/7
---- snip ----

So both bash4 an ksh93 keep a fd to the shell script ("shellfd.ksh")
around (I even tried /usr/bin/shcomp to make shell bytecode, but the
issue remains...)

And here comes the nasty part: If shellfd.ksh is on a network
filesystem (in my test setup my home dir, mounted at H:), then in some
cases (I do not know why) a $ net use Z: /delete # will fail with
error #1794 if both network filesystems are from the same server.

This is NOT the same as the script tries to unmount the filesystem it
is residing on - Z: is mounted separately, and a different exported
directory than H:, and yet I can reproduce that issue (after around
30-40 experiments, until I remembered that ksh93 keeps a fd to the
script open).

This sounds a lot like a Windows bug.

Martin: Do you have more than one network filesystem mounted on your machine ?

----

Bye,
Roland

P.S.: There is no way to close the fd to the script from within the
same script, e.g. $ command exec 10<&- # will the trigger the shell
interpreters just to |dup()| the fd to another number.
```